# check if file selected in field array in php

Tags: php, multiple-file-upload

I have to update database which consists of multiple fields of file input type.
name of all input fields are same.

```
<input type="text" name="title[]">
<input type="file" name="image[]">
<input type="text" name="title[]">
<input type="file" name="image[]">
<input type="text" name="title[]">
<input type="file" name="image[]">
```

Now it is not mandatory that all images are selected, there might be chances that all title are changed but only 3rd image is selected. Now i want to upload file only if image is selected else escape uploading.

this is action page:

```
    <?php
      $title = $_POST['title'];

$upload = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($title); $i++)
    {
       if(!empty($_FILES['image'][$i]))
       {
           // upload file and set flag upload=1
       } else {
           // set flag upload=0
       }

       if($upload == 1)
       {
          $qry = "UPDATE <table_name> SET title='$title[$i]', image='$image' WHERE <match found>";
          // execute $qry
       } else {
          $qry = "UPDATE <table_name> SET title='$title[$i]' WHERE <match found>";
          // execute $qry
       }
    }
```

but every time only `else` statement is running event when image is selected and even when image is not selected.

> Update 2 : Result of `print_r($_FILES);`

```
Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => Selection_238.png
                    [2] => 
                )
            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => image/png
                    [2] => 
                )
            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => /tmp/phpqSB0Jn
                    [2] => 
                )
            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 4
                )
            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 72259
                    [2] => 0
                )
        )
)
```

*Selected Image in 2nd input field*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to change `=` to `==` in your code `if($upload = 1)`. because `=` is `assignment` operator not `comparison`operator.

Check it and may be your problem is solved. Otherwise please check below possible solution

**1.**

```
<?php
  $title = $_POST['title'];

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($title); $i++)
{
   if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]))
   {
       // check if file uploaded then run below query
        $qry = "UPDATE <table_name> SET title='$title[$i]', image='$image' WHERE <match found>"; // you can apply if else here based on move_uploaded_file output       
   } else {
       // set flag upload=0
        $qry = "UPDATE <table_name> SET title='$title[$i]' WHERE <match found>";
   }
}
?>
```

**2.**

```
<?php
  $title = $_POST['title'];
    $upload = 0; // define here
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($title); $i++)
{
   if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]))
   {
       // upload file and set flag $upload = 1
   } else {
       // set flag $upload = 0
   }

   if($upload == 1) // you need to change = (assignment) to  == (comparision)
   {
      $qry = "UPDATE <table_name> SET title='$title[$i]', image='$image' WHERE <match found>";
      // execute $qry
   } else {
      $qry = "UPDATE <table_name> SET title='$title[$i]' WHERE <match found>";
      // execute $qry
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: I have corrected code in question (that was typing mistake). Actually, I tried print `echo 'in if condition... ';` in `if(!empty($_FILES['image'][$i])) { echo 'in if condition...'; }` but it prints nothing..

Comment: first of all try to check `echo "<pre/>";print_r($_FILES);` before any condition.And check what is showing? put that into the question.

Comment: I have updated question with the result of `print_r($_FILES);`.

Comment: you have to add `['name']` also there . Please check my edited answer